# Weighted average in python-pandas dataframe with weights given

Tags: python, pandas, mean, weighted

I would like to get weighted mean of three columns below and below is what I tried

```
data = [[10,20,30], [20,30,10],[30,40,50],[10,15,20]]  
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['size', 'price','distance'])
```

My weights average would be 0.3*size+0.5*price+0.2*distance

```
df['weighted_mean']=df[[0.3*'size',0.5*'price',0.2*'distance']].mean(1)
```

Below is my error

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

How can I fix this?
Thank you.

Comment: `(df * [0.3, 0.5, 0.2]).mean(1)`.  I don't think you quite grasp pandas indexing, because what you are trying to do makes no sense.

Comment: Actually I have more columns and I need to specify column names. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Create a series where the weight name matches the column name

Comment: (df[[size, price,distance]]* [0.3, 0.5, 0.2]).mean(1)

Comment: Sure you could do that, or create the series if you want to be more explicit.  You should really read about both index alignment and pandas basic indexing.

Answer (score 2):

You should multiply the *values* that are in the columns, not the column names themselves, like:

```
df['weighted_mean']= 0.3*df['size'] + 0.5*df['price'] + 0.2*df['distance']
```

since the weights sum up to 1.0, there is no need for division here.

For your given data, this will result in:

```
>>> 0.3*df['size'] + 0.5*df['price'] + 0.2*df['distance']
0    19.0
1    23.0
2    39.0
3    14.5
dtype: float64
```

We can generalize the above with a dictionary, like:

```
def weighted_sum(df, weights):
    return df[list(weights)].mul(weights).sum(axis=1) / sum(weights.values())
```

For example:

```
>>> weighted_sum(df, {'size': 0.3, 'price': 0.5, 'distance': 0.2})
0    19.0
1    23.0
2    39.0
3    14.5
dtype: float64
```

If all weights are multiplied by two, then there is no difference:

```
>>> weighted_sum(df, {'size': 0.6, 'price': 1.0, 'distance': 0.4})
0    19.0
1    23.0
2    39.0
3    14.5
dtype: float64
```

If we however increase one value, we see that the result is different:

```
>>> weighted_sum(df, {'size': 0.3, 'price': 1.0, 'distance': 0.2})
0    19.333333
1    25.333333
2    39.333333
3    14.666667
dtype: float64
```

**Performance**: if we run the `weighted_sum` 1'000 times on the given dataset with the given weights, we retrieve the following benchmarks:

```
>>> timeit(partial(weighted_sum, df, {'size': 0.3, 'price': 1.0, 'distance': 0.2}), number=1000)
1.3530528700212017
```

So this rougly runs in 1.353ms per call in an *Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz*.